# Error when using EXTRACT function to get year or month from a timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a query that is to return New Users By `Month` i.e The count of first-time transactions grouped by `Phone Number`, by `month` & `year`.

Here is my query:

```
select extract(year from timestamp FirstOrderDate) as yr, 
       extract(month from timestamp FirstOrderDate) as mon,
       count(*)
FROM (
   SELECT /*The column referred to below is character varying(50) - it is unfortunately not data type date*/
          TO_DATE(MIN("Date_Transaction_Occured"),'mm-dd-yyyy') AS FirstOrderDate
   FROM "TABLE1"
   group by "PhoneNumber"
) AS FirstOrderTable;
group by extract(year from date FirstOrderDate), 
extract(month from date FirstOrderDate);
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FirstOrderDate"
LINE 1: ...AS total FROM (select extract(year from timestamp FirstOrder...

              ^
```

Comment: I don't see any `total` in your query. Please post your entire query

Comment: there is no total in my query, there is count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `timestamp` keyword - that is only needed when specifying a constant value, not when referencing a column of type date or timestamp:

```
select extract(year from FirstOrderDate) as yr, 
       extract(month from FirstOrderDate) as mon,
       count(*)
FROM ...
group by extract(year from FirstOrderDate), 
         extract(month from FirstOrderDate);
```

Comment: After removing the timestamp keyword, I received the following error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "count"
LINE 1: ...e) as yr, extract(month from FirstOrderDate) as mon count(*)

Comment: @MichaelLynch: did you notice that I added a `,` before the `count(*) `

Comment: I made the change and it worked, thank you very much.